# QGIS 3.22 support for topocentric CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I simply try to convert a point from local Cartesian ENU centered on a point with lat,lon coordinates to geocentric ECEF coordinates.
With proj from command line all works well.
I use strings from proj to create QGIS CRS.
But using QGIS I receive:

> Error transforming "forward transform of\n (inf,inf)\n Error: Fallback transformation failed"

So I'm wondering, does QGIS 3.22 support conversion from a local Cartesian to ECEF?

```
void geoutils::TopoToECEF(const QgsPointXY &origin, const QgsPointXY &point, QgsPointXY &point_wgs)
{

    try {

        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem geocentricCRS;

        QString projStringGeocentric = "+proj=cart +ellps=GRS80";  //ECEF CRS
        bool res= geocentricCRS.createFromProj(projStringGeocentric);
        qDebug() << "result 1 is " << res << geocentricCRS.toProj();  // this return true !!!

        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem topocentricCRS;

        QString projStringTopocentric = "+proj=topocentric +ellps=WGS84";
        projStringTopocentric += " +lon_0=9"; // origin lon
        projStringTopocentric += " +lat_0=44"; // origin lat
        projStringTopocentric += " +h_0=0 +units=m"; //

        res = topocentricCRS.createFromProj(projStringTopocentric);

        qDebug() << "result 2 is " << res << topocentricCRS.toProj(); //this return true !!!

        QgsProject::instance()->setCrs(geocentricCRS);

        QgsCoordinateTransform *xformerFromToTopocentricToWgs84 = new QgsCoordinateTransform(topocentricCRS, geocentricCRS, QgsProject::instance());  // src, dest, proj

        qDebug() << "TopoToECEF Input point x: " << point.x() << " y: "<< point.y();
        point_wgs = xformerFromToTopocentricToWgs84->transform(point);   // this BOOOMMMSS !!

        qDebug() << "TopoToECEF -  Output x: " << point_wgs.x() << "  y: "<< point_wgs.y();

    }  catch (const QgsException& e) {
        qDebug() << "error transforming " << e.what();

    }
 }
```